# When and how to adopt a method into a class?

Tags: ruby

Below is some code I wrote to solve a problem for a course I'm taking. The solution that I have works just fine, however the question called for using a class implementation, meaning we are to adopt whatever solution we come up with into a class. In the first block below is the method that I wrote, and in the second block is the class implementation of the method, they both do pretty much the same thing. However, I am failing to see the benefit of the class adaptation. Also I don't particularly know how much is too much or too little for a single class method to do on it's own. Do I compartmentalize everything? Or do I keep operations that pertain to a certain thing packaged in a single method?

```
def cipher(coded_message)
  input = coded_message.downcase.split("")
  cipher = {}
  alphabet_array = %w(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)
  alphabet_array.each_with_index {|e,i|  cipher[e] = alphabet_array[i-4]}
   (0..9).to_a.each{|e| cipher[e.to_s] = e}
  %w[@ # $ % ^ & *].each{|e| cipher[e] = " "}
  %w[. , ! ? ; : -].each{|e| cipher[e] = e}
  input.map! {|e| e = cipher[e]}
  input = input.join("")
  if input.match(/\d+/)
    input.gsub!(/\d+/) { |num| num.to_i / 100 }
  end
  return input
end
```

```
class Cipher
  def initialize(shift=4,exaggerate=100)
    @shift = shift
    @exaggerate = exaggerate
  end

  def create_cipher
    @cipher = {}
    @alphabet_array = ('a'..'z').to_a
    @alphabet_array.each_with_index {|e,i| @cipher[e] = @alphabet_array[i - @shift]}
    (0..9).to_a.each{|e| @cipher[e.to_s] = e}
    %w[@ # $ % ^ & *].each{|e| @cipher[e] = " "}
    %w[. , ! ? ; : -].each{|e| @cipher[e] = e}
  end

    def decode(input=nil)
      @input = input
      create_cipher
      @input = @input.downcase.split("")
      @input.map! {|e| e = @cipher[e]}
      @input = @input.join("")
      if @input.match(/\d+/)
        @input.gsub!(/\d+/) { |num| num.to_i / @exaggerate }
      end
      return @input
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the biggest benefit of moving that code from a method into a class is testability and maintainablity. It is easier to test in isolation and that new class will probably be stable for a long period of time.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Would you say that I've packed too much into the two methods in the class? I'm really trying to get a feel for how fine-grained methods inside of a class should be